# Android app main content is above title bar

Tags: android, xml, layout, xamarin.android

Im building an android app in visual studio. in my feed.axml file my main body content is floating above my title bar. it should be below the title bar. i am confused as to why my code is doing this.

[my android app as of this post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfJwP.png)
the content which is shown in this image that is above the title bar is a card and large text. if anyone knows how to float these elements below the title bar please tell me.

any help would be appreciated

here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cardView1" />
        <TextView
            android:text="hello world"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You have the `<CardView>` and the `<TextView>` listed before the toolbar `<include>` in a vertical `<LinearLayout>`. If you want them below, move them to after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<include
  layout="@layout/toolbar" />
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cardView1" />
        <TextView
            android:text="hello world"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

LinearLayout places its child linearly, so you need to do something like this.
You can also place your toolbar thingy somewhere before CardView